# Read data from serial port and keep track of most recent lines read

Tags: c#, arrays, logging, serial-port

Here is my problem. I have about 20 different types of messages coming in through a port. they can all be identified and come in at different rates (some come multiple times per second, some once every couple of seconds.)

I need to keep a log of these items, but only log them every 30 minutes. I would like to constantly read the port, and update an array of some sort. then when the timer event occurs, log the data from the array.

I am doing this in C# .net 4.5.2

Comment: What you are calling a problem is actually a task that you need to do. Please show us what you have done so far for your task and then we can help with something specific you are having issues with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of lists to organize this type of in-memory log. If you create say

```
public enum EventTypes
{
    A,
    B
};
```

and assuming your data points are integers, you could use

```
Dictionary<EventTypes, List<int>> inMemoryLog = new Dictionary<EventTypes, List<int>>();
```

Then you could log like this:

```
inMemoryLog[EventTypes.A].Add(myDataPoint);
```

When you're ready to flush the log to memory, persist the inMemoryLog to disk, removing each entry that you have written out. It may be a good strategy to create a copy of inMemoryLog to use to write to disk (and then re-initialize the imMemoryLog instance you use for logging) so that in-memory logging can continue without interruption.

Comment: thanks Eric! this is actually what I was looking into over the weekend and very excited to implement.